# Find $\arg z$ if $z = \frac{(\sin\theta -i\cos\theta)^4}{(\cos\theta - i\sin\theta)^3}$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

The aim is to estimate  $\arg z$ for $z = \frac{(\sin\theta -i\cos\theta)^4}{(\cos\theta - i\sin\theta)^3}$. One thing that I thought is to find the $|z|$ and then write   $z$ in the trigonometric form s.t $z = |z|(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)$, and finally to consider that

$|z|(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)= \frac{(\sin\theta -i\cos\theta)^4}{(\cos\theta - i\sin\theta)^3}$. But, it is not clear for me if this can help.

Have you got any idea of how to find the argz?

Comment: $\sin \theta -i\cos \theta=-i e^{i\theta}$ and $\cos \theta -i\sin \theta= e^{-i\theta}$. So $z=e^{7i\theta}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you for your comment. Is this the only way to solve the problem? I mean that I didn't expect that I have to change to exponential form !!

Comment: This is the best way. You don't have to use any trig. identities for $\cos (2x), \cos (3x), \sin(2x), \sin (3x)$ etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$z=\frac{(i(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta))^4}{\cos(-3\theta)+i\sin(-3\theta)}=i^4\cdot\frac{\cos4\theta+i\sin4\theta}{\cos(-3\theta)+i\sin(-3\theta)}=\cos7\theta+i\sin7\theta.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you give more details about the $i^4$ and which properties did you use for cos and sin ? Furthermore, how can I find the Argz from the $cos7\theta +isin7\theta$ ?  $Argz = 7\theta$ ?

Comment: @Dimitris Dimitriadis  I added something. Your last question depend on how you define an argument. $0\leq\arg{z}<2\pi$ or $-\pi<\arg{z}\leq\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

$$z = \frac{(\sin\theta -i\cos\theta)^4}{(\cos\theta - i\sin\theta)^3}=\frac{\left(i(\cos\theta +i\sin\theta)\right)^4}{(\cos(-\theta) + i\sin(-\theta))^3}=\\=\frac{\cos 4\theta+i\sin 4\theta}{\cos (-3\theta)+i\sin(-3\theta)}=\cos(7\theta)+i\sin(7\theta)$$
Thus $\arg z = 7\theta$